# Native Crash in /system/lib/libart.so art::gc::collector on Android 6.0

Tags: android, garbage-collection

I get reports of these crashes from users of my app on Android 6.0 devices. The crash stack doesn't contain any keywords of my source code. I can't determined what caused the problem and don't know what to do. What's wrong with it? :(

```
SIGSEGV(SEGV_MAPERR):
#00 pc 0018b7fc /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::FillWithDummyObject(art::mirror::Object*, unsigned int)+1195) [armeabi-v7a::bd556bcd01d8c215f5cd133343e0a883]
#01 pc 0018ba89 /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::ProcessMarkStack(bool)+100) [armeabi-v7a::bd556bcd01d8c215f5cd133343e0a883]
java:
java.lang.Daemons$HeapTaskDaemon.run(Daemons.java:386)
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)



SIGSEGV(SEGV_MAPERR):
#00 pc 001976fc /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::ConcurrentCopying::Copy(art::mirror::Object*)+923) [armeabi-v7a::44966e008bb1c7f64243a7db7f321398]
#01 pc 001979a1 /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::ProcessMarkStack(bool)+112) [armeabi-v7a::44966e008bb1c7f64243a7db7f321398]
……
#55 pc 001979a1 /system/lib/libart.so (art::gc::collector::MarkSweep::ProcessMarkStack(bool)+112) [armeabi-v7a::44966e008bb1c7f64243a7db7f321398]
#56 pc 001979a1 /system/lib/libart.so (_ZN3art2gc9collec
```

Comment: Did you get a solution for this?